# Azure DevOps Services taskboard not showing task which is linked as child to a bug

Tags: azure

we have switched from TFS2017 (on premise) to Azure DevOps Services. Everything works fine but we have a problem with the taskboard. In our old TFS 2017 taskboard we can see the tasks which are linked as childs to a bug.
In Azure DevOps Services we do not see a task on the taskboard which is linked as child to a bug.

Bug:
[Linking of the task in the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQhQV.png)

Task:
[Linking of the bug in the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCJpg.png)

In the taskboard no task is shown. The iteration of the work items are set to the sprint (19_34).
[Taskboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zugw.png)

Is there anything that i have not considered? In TFS 2017 it is the same linking and it works. Also the settings are the same as in TFS 2017.

Kind regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have wrong parent-child relation. Read how to [Fix re-ordering and nesting issues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/resolve-backlog-reorder-issues?view=azure-devops). There is also project backlog settings, where you can choose your [preferences for tracking bugs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=azure-devops) - changing it to another option will probably solve your problem.